# Silverlight tabcontrol with external Page as content

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I am new to silverlight. I'm trying to convert a jquery tabcontrol page to a SL 4. on my previous page each tab was containing an iframe with its URL to an external page. Let's say, the first one is http://Google.com, the second one is http://Microsoft.com etc.How can i make in SL.

Comment: I'm not sure what you hope to gain from doing this in silverlight at all?  Whats wrong with the jquery solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SL 4 introduced a [Web browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.webbrowser%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) control which used to be available only in 3rd party offers previously (ComponentOne for instance)

So you just have to add two tabs to your tab control, define a web browser control as the content of each tab and call Navigate to go to a specific Url

Comment: Note the WebBrowser control only works when SL is running out of browser.